# Not populating tableview with structure array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to populate my tableView with an array of a structure. The first property of the structure is the name. This is what I tried...

```
var menuArray:[Restaurant] = [Restaurant]()
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let shake = Item(name: "Shake", carbs: 20)
    let fries = Item(name: "Fries", carbs: 30)

    let beverages = Category(name: "Beverages", items: [shake])
    let chips_fries = Category(name: "Chips & Fries", items: [fries])
    let desserts = Category(name: "Desserts", items: [])
    let other = Category(name: "Other Menu Items", items: [])
    let sandwiches_burgers = Category(name: "Sandwiches & Burgers", items: [])
    let sides = Category(name: "Sides", items: [])

    a_w = Restaurant(name: "A&W", categories: [beverages, chips_fries, desserts, other, sandwiches_burgers, sides])

    let menuArray = [a_w]


}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    let currentRestaurant = menuArray[indexPath.row]
    currentCell?.textLabel!.text = currentRestaurant.name
    return currentCell!
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return menuArray.count
}
```

Why won't it populate my tableView

Here is my class also...

```
import Foundation

struct Item {
    let name: String
    let carbs: Int
}

struct Category {
    let name: String
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Restaurant {
    let name: String
    let categories: [Category]

}
```

Comment: Have you tried reloading table view after setting its data?

Comment: yes it didn't work

Comment: Have you set delegate and data source for table view?

Comment: Its a tableviewcontroller

Comment: `let menuArray` looks like a local variable. How is the data source array declared?

Comment: where you have been declared **menuArray** variable? I mean is it at class level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
let menuArray = [a_w]
```

you are creating a local variable `menuArray` which is different from the property with the same name representing the data source array.

Omit `let`

```
menuArray = [a_w]
```

PS: Please use more descriptive variable names than `a_w`.

Comment: Thanks so much that was exactly it

Answer (score 0):

From you code looks like you have two variables with same name.

1. One is declared at class level
2. Another one is declared in viewDidLoad method like

   let menuArray = [a_w]

Just remove **let** from this which is declared in viewDidLoad.

It will look like this

```
menuArray = [a_w]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your menuArray containse only one item so only one row should be displayed with the restaurant name.
Try checking if you set the tableView delegate and dataSource properties
`tableView.dataSource = self
 tableView.delegate = self`

Also the prototype cell with default label should have name titleLabel
Try accessing `titleLabel` instead of `textLabel`.